# Highchart event LOAD is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

```
function drawGraph($scope) {
    //console.log("in draw graph");
    //console.log(graphName);
    //console.log($scope.chartCategories);
    //console.log($scope.chartSeries);
    $scope.chartConfig = {
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random();
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        console.log(x + y);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y: Math.random()
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }())
        }]
    }
}
```

Every thing is working fine. Chart is creating etc etc. but the only issue is that chart is not dynamically changing i.e. i thinks the load event in chart:{} is not executing or something because it is not even logging in console. Kindly Help me. Same thing is running at [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in highcharts-ng. See related topics: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/search?q=load&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Answer (score 0):

Try redrawing the chart after updating data.

```
load: function() {

    // set up the updating of the chart each second
    var series = this.series[0];
    var chart = this;
    setInterval(function() {
        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
            y = Math.random();
        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
        chart.redraw();
        console.log(x + y);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Same! load function is not even invoking :S

Comment: How is this supposed to help? He just said the event is not firing.